# Why is this for loop infinitely looping? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop

This is really strange. This program was working fine on another computer, but when  I try it on this one it runs forever. Also it is a for loop, which adds even more to my confusion. SIZE_OF_DATA is a preprocessor variable, which I think might be causing the problem.. But I don't know. When I add a printf, it shows only one iteration of the outside loop and is looping infinitely in the inner loop. I have no idea why.

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    for(j=0;j<SIZE_OF_DATA; j++){
      aArray[i*SIZE_OF_DATA + j] = aPointer[i]->b[j]; 
      cArray[i*SIZE_OF_DATA + j] = 0;                            
      dArray[i*SIZE_OF_DATA + j] = i*SIZE_OF_DATA + j;
      if (i==0)
        eArray[j] = 0;
    }
  }
```

I'm worried that I somehow destroyed my program... But I have barely done anything but add comments!

Comment: How is your `SIZE_OF_DATA` defined?

Comment: Not only that, but how is `j` defined?

Comment: SIZE_OF_DATA is defined as a preprocessor variable equal to 10. J is just defined as an int.

Comment: What was the result if you used printf(j) in the inner loop?

Comment: Actually I figured it out. One of my arrays was indeed out of bounds (by one element from a rounding error). Looks like my i and j got clobbered only in certain inputs, which is why I got the error on one computer but not another.

Comment: @AndrewB - strong hint: debug first, post later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
aArray[i*SIZE_OF_DATA + j]
```

looks like you might be writing outside the array (`cArray` and `dArray` too) in the last iteration. Are you sure you're getting a correct index into the array? If not, through the wonders of undefined behavior, you are probably writing to memory that belongs to other variables, including `i` and `j`, which could make this loop go on forever.

Buggy programs with undefined behavior behave very... undefined. Though without seeing more code, no one can be sure.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to debugging this piece of code would be to print the values i and j in the for loop. Perhaps `SIZE_OF_DATA` increases unintentionally in some block of your code although this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting i * SIZE_OF_DATA + j to a variable, that may be where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please mention the data type of 'j'. I assume that if suppose the data type of 'j' is char and your value of 'SIZE_OF_DATA' macro is some thing like 150. then the value of 'j' will be iterated between -128 to 127. So it will run infinitely